# ImageMagick - Transform Outline Image to Perfect Black And White, WIth No Noise

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I am looking for an image magick command that will help me transform black and white outline images (doodle sketches) to perfect white background and perfect lines (even no antialiasing) that are black. I need this, so I can then convert them to perfect centerline SVG using autotrace.

The problem is that I cannot make a command that will fit all images that I process.
Here are 2 images I want to convert:
[image: IMAGE1]
[image: IMAGE2]

If you look at IMAGE2, I want to remove all the white spots and noise sorounding the black lines.
I tried a lot of combinations and commands, but nothing works.
The closest command that almost worked is:
`convert 2.png -threshold 50%% -negate -morphology Dilate Diamond:1 -negate -gaussian-blur 1  -unsharp 0x1 77.ppm`

I tried using other parameters like:
`+level-colors black,  -statistic mean 15x15 -level 25%,75%  -canny 0x1+10%+30%  -blur 0x10 -unsharp 0x10`
But can't get the good results I am looking for.

In IMAGE2 I especially want to remove all the "fuzziness" as shown bellow, but maintaining a clear black line there:
[image]

Any help is appreciated. My main goal is to then use the obtained image to get the centerline tracing using autotrace.
One of the main issues is the right eye of the dog, it's very close to the head, and between the head line and the right eye, there are noisy pixels. I want to turn them to perfect white, so I can delimitate everything perfectly and obtain clear black lines on a perfect white background (even without antialiasing).

EDIT1: IT seems for me, for image 2 (child with dog) when I apply threshold, I get different results than others are getting. I am using image magick 7.1.1 . Can you please try to apply threshold on the image https://sodevrom.net/2.png (this exact image) and let me know if you get good results?

EDIT2: The command -blur 0x1  -threshold 50%%  -blur 0x1 gets me the desired result for image2. The problem with image1 is that the lines are very thin. And when I apply the same command, some lines get cut off like shown here.
https://imgur.com/xST1WRq
I do not want this to happen. Any ideas?

EDIT3: I found the final command that works for me.
convert 2.png  -threshold 50%% -negate -morphology Open Diamond:1 -negate -blur 0x1 77.ppm

This works perfect for IMAGE2, and -morphology Dilate Diamond:1 works perfect for IMAGE1. Will find a compromise since it will be hard to make it perfect for all types of images.

Comment: There should be no fuzziness if you just use -threshold 50% and nothing else following it but the output image. Most other processing in your command will add fuzziness back.

Comment: Once you have antialiasing, if you threshold you may get stair-stepping.  You won't be able to remove the stairstepping and make a smooth edge on the black lines. Even if you could, the fact that the image is digital (pixels), means you will have stair stepping on diagonal edges.  What are you actually trying to do?  What do you mean by "crisp"

Comment: Using -threhold 50% gets me this: https://imgur.com/rKbfNj5 So it's not what I am looking for. I am looking for black and white image. Even if it has the staircase effect with no antialiasing.

Comment: Slight Gaussian or Median blur, followed by Threshold or high contrast: https://i.imgur.com/d0sZpCd.png

Comment: Try `convert image -negate -threshold 0 -negate` result. or just use a different threshold than 50% (something larger such 75% or 90%).

Comment: @xenoid can you please tell me the exact command you used?

Comment: I tried the command with Gimp. Gaussian with 1.50/1.50, then Brightness-Contrast with Contrast +96. You can of course find/use the equivalent with IM.

Answer (score 1):

Is this better in Imagemagick 7?  Add -blur 0x1 to command.

```
magick image1.jpg -blur 0x1 -auto-level -threshold 50% result1.png
```

[image]

```
magick image2.png -blur 0x1 -auto-level -threshold 50% result2.png
```

[image]

If not, try increasing to -blur 0x2.

Alternately try adding -morphology open diamond:2 to the command as

```
magick image1.jpg -auto-level -threshold 50% -morphology open diamond:2 result5.png
```

[image]

```
magick image2.png -auto-level -threshold 50% -morphology open diamond:2 result6.png
```

[image]

Increase the diamond:X size if desired or change the open to erode to thicken the lines.

Comment: Thank you. Using  -blur 0x1 -threshold 50%% -blur 0x1 gets great results for image 2. But please try with image https://sodevrom.net/77.jpg  Unfortunately it does not work with that because the lines are so thin.

Comment: As I said above, adding -blur AFTER -threshold will introduce values other than 0 and 255.  Try -blur 0x1 -threshold 50%% -morphology open diamond:1 or diamond:2

Answer (score 0):

Add -auto-level to the threshold 50% command to stretch the black to 0 and the white to 255 in Imagemagick.

**Unix IM 6 syntax:**

```
convert image1.jpg -auto-level -threshold 50% result1.png
```

[image]

```
convert image2.png -auto-level -threshold 50% result2.png
```

[image]

*For IM 7 use magick rather than convert.  For Windows, escape the % to %%.*

Comment: I am using image magick 7.1.1 and I do not get this result. I get https://i.imgur.com/d0sZpCd.png  Try the command on image https://sodevrom.net/2.png  Does it work for you? Even if it works, the result is not exactly what I need. I want to remove the individual points of noise like https://imgur.com/ut5mdQx

Comment: On Imagemagick 7, use magick rather than convert.

Comment: Very strange, same result. I used magick 2.png -auto-level -threshold 50% 77.ppm  and I get https://imgur.com/vewnlwH  I tried installing image magick 6.9 also (legacy), and again, I get the same image

Comment: Are we using the same image?  What was your exact version of IM 7.1.1.X?  What do you get from `magick -version`.  You may have a buggy version of IM.  What platform?

Comment: If you are on Windows you need to escape the % to %%. So try `magick 2.png -auto-level -threshold 50%% 77.ppm`

Comment: I was on windows ... thanks a lot for that. The final command that achieved the results I was looking for was -blur 0x1  -threshold 50%%  -blur 0x1

Comment: Adding -blur after -threshold will produce values other than 0 and 255. I thought you did not want that?

Comment: After removing all noise, I want to add "antialiasing" back. I am doing tests with centerline autotrace on the images, after I process them. If they have no antialias, they are not traced

Comment: OK, then I understand why you add -blur at the end.  Try thickening your lines a little before the final -blur using -morphology erode diamond:1 or diamond2 after the threshold.  or do your final blur but add -level 0x50%%  or possibly -level 50x100%% (try each to see which is better/correct) after the final blur.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another thought.  JPG images have compression artifacts that need at least 15% thresholding to remove. So let's use 25% rather than 50% in our thresholding in Imagemagick.

**Unix Imagemagick 7 syntax:**

```
magick image1.jpg -auto-level -threshold 25% -morphology open diamond:2 result7.png
```

[image]

```
magick image2.png -auto-level -threshold 25% -morphology open diamond:2 result8.png
```

[image]

** For Windows escape the % to %%. For Imageamgick 6, replace magick with convert**